# Updating d3 circle pack layout with new Object

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, circle-pack

Still some problems with updating the circle pack layout:

I would like to add an object to an already existing circle:

This works fine for circles, which already have children. But not for leaf-circles. Although the adapted `data1`seems to be correct, 6 is replacing a circle 2 instead of becoming a child of it.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/stefanf/jmKH6/27/

```
obj = {
    "name": 6,
    "analysis_id" : 6,
    "time" : 30
}
```

Comment: If you run Inspect Element you'll see that it's not being replaced. Instead `6` is being drawn over `2` which actually becomes a `node`. So maybe revisit how you are updating the nodes.

Comment: Seems it is not working without adding as well: http://jsfiddle.net/stefanf/jmKH6/33/ instead of 5, there should be 4 with 5 as child..

Comment: Seems this is what it should do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307486/d3-js-packed-circle-layout-how-to-adjust-child-radius?answertab=oldest#tab-top. So for only one child, the radius is the same as the parents! :/