# d3js Circle Pack diagram with nested single child arrays

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a pack diagram based on this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530

Here is a jsbin illustrating the problem.http://jsbin.com/xukufi/1/edit?js,output

Using the code form the example if you have nested arrays of children with a single child the bottom most child overlaps all the others, so you cannot see or interact with any of the parent objects.

In my jsbin I've overcome this by checking for the number of siblings and decreasing the circle radius by a third. This works, but messes up the node layout if any of this single children have multiple nodes in them. I've got the radius problem figured out, but I can't figure out how to position the x and y for the circles.

I may be going off track at this point. Has anyone else dealt with this problem with how d3 renders the circle pack?

Comment: possible duplicate of [D3.js packed circle layout - how to adjust child radius](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307486/d3-js-packed-circle-layout-how-to-adjust-child-radius)

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. How I couldn't find this answer myself is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Ben's link solved my problem. This is indeed a duplicate.